# Why using POST?

Tags: android, post, get, httpurlconnection

Is there any reason to use POST method in HttpURLConnection?
It is easier for me to use just GET, but I need to send password.
So is there any big risk when sending password by GET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no difference in case of security.
You can send your password with GET if it's simpler to implement.
but in both case password has to be hashed before sending it, if you are worried about the security.